# Angular: Instantiating objects based on http response array within a parent object

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript and have been struggling with trying to get this one figured out.

I have a http response that is shaped like this:

```
{     
     "data": [
          {
              "id": 14950,
              "bookingId": 5377,
              "interactionType": 10,
              "interactionTypeDescription": "Booking viewed by partner",
              "interactionDateTime": "2023-04-28T12:27:28.6818618",
              "userId": 152
          },
          {   "id": 14951,
              "bookingId": 5377,
              "interactionType": 11,
              "interactionTypeDescription": "Booking viewed by customer",
              "interactionDateTime": "2023-04-29T11:11:08.6649318",
              "userId": 778
           }
      ]
}
```

For each object in the response, I need to instantiate the below class and return an array.

```
export class BookingInteractionsResponseModel {
public id: number;
bookingId: number;
interactionType: number;
interactionText: string;
interactionDateTime: string;
userId: number;

    constructor(id: number, bookingId: number, interactionType: number, interactionTypeDescription: string,
                    interactionDateTime: string, userId: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
        this.interactionType = interactionType;
        this.interactionTypeDescription = interactionTypeDescription;
        this.interactionDateTime = interactionDateTime;
        this.userId = userId;
     }
.
.
.
```

I've been able to make this work with a *response that does not have the parent "data"*, using this function:

```
fetchBookingInteractions(bookingId: number): Observable<BookingInteractionsResponseModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<BookingInteractionsResponseModel[]>(url)
        .pipe(
             map ( interactions => {
                 return interactions.map ( interaction => {
                     return new BookingInteractionsResponseModel(
                                               interaction.id,
                                               interaction.bookingId,
                                               interaction.interactionType,
                                               interaction.interactionTypeDescription,
                                               interaction.interactionDateTime,
                                               interaction.userId
                      )
                  })
            })
      );
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the above when the response is encapsulated within the "data" object.

Couple of notes:

1. I'm not able to use an interface here
2. I haven't asked many questions on SO, so please let me know if my question does not make sense or meet requirements
3. Thank you in advance for your help!

I've tried adding to the "map/return" at various levels but I'm still unable to get the correct mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy, you can make it like this:

```
fetchBookingInteractions(bookingId: number): Observable<BookingInteractionsResponseModel[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<{data: BookingInteractionsResponseModel[]}>(url)
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        return response.data.map(interaction => {
          return new BookingInteractionsResponseModel(
            interaction.id,
            interaction.bookingId,
            interaction.interactionType,
            interaction.interactionTypeDescription,
            interaction.interactionDateTime,
            interaction.userId
          );
        });
      })
    );
}
```